# General mysql freeze

Tags: mysql

Our MySQL server is behaving strangely - doing a heavy query on one table will pretty much lock it, no other query will be responded to, even if it's a trivial one on completely unrelated table (like `SELECT` by primary key, `INSERT`, or even `EXPLAIN`) - it will just wait for the heavy one to finish.
 I'm really out of ideas what could be causing that - there's plenty of free threads, CPU is in idle/wait state, network is free, there's plenty of memory ... etc.
 Anybody has any ideas what to look for?

Comment: 1. What does "pretty much" lock it mean? :) Are other queries _sometime_ served?
2. This heavy query - does it use lots of joins? can you tell a bit more about it?

Comment: The freeze doesn't seem completely deterministic, but when it's frozen, it's frozen for good until the query is served. If it takes over 1 hour, everething else waits over 1 hour too, then gets served a few seconds after the big one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

How much memory does MySQL have? My guess is that it's having to go to disk for temporary tables and that can be killer. How big is your innodb_buffer_pool_size in your my.cnf/my.ini file? By increasing that (which ups memory usage) smaller queries (and queries that need to do lots of sorting) won't have to hit disk.

The next time a query starts to do this to you, log onto MySQL, do "show full processlist" and record what's there. If you issue an EXPLAIN or a DESCRIBE on the query that's going slow, what does it is? Does it include the note that it's going to a temporary table?

When MySQL starts using temp tables, things can feel like they are dying, especially if you don't have a fast disk.